# Random Wallpaper Folder

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization

I've been shuffling random desktop backgrounds with the built-in Windows 7 feature. What I want to do is shuffle backgrounds from a folder; where I'd drop in pictures at different times and the new wallpapers will automatically be used.

I've set the folder to my wallpaper folder, but I'm not sure if new wallpapers will be automatically added. Do I have to open up the Desktop Background window to update the wallpaper collection with the folder contents or does this happen automatically?

If this doesn't happen automatically, is there a 3rd party random wallpaper shuffler we can use?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, wallpapers will be automatically updated with the folder contents.